# Rails - How to save a hash to the DB and using it as a hash once you pull it form the DB (not pulling it as a sting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

If I save a hash to the DB

```
hash_value = {"1"=>"val1", "2"=>"val2", "3"=>"val3", "4"=>"val4"}
@page.update(hash: hash_value)
```

Then try and loop through each key of the hash on the `page` page

```
hash = @page.hash 

<%= hash.each do |key, value| %>

 <%= value %>

<% end %>
```

I get the error `undefined method 'each' for #<String:0x007fdda1d8b568>`. This error made me realise it is saved saved as a string to the DB.

How do I make it save as a hash so when I pull it rom the DB it is in a hash not a string? Doing some research I found `serialize` but I cant make out how to use it properly. Is it used to change the DB table to have all values saved in that table be hashes? If so what is added in the migration file to do that?

```
    create_table :pages do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
      t.text  :title
      t.text  :content_top
      t.text  :content_bottom
      t.text  :hash

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

Just confused as to how saving a hash to the DB and calling it as a hash is accomplished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The column type for :hash on :pages table is text, which is the correct column type to use when you wish for a column to store a hash. You must now also indicate on the Page model that you wish to serialize this column. Something like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :hash
```

Then you can attempt to test your new setup like this:

```
@page = Page.new
@page.hash = {"1"=>"val1", "2"=>"val2", "3"=>"val3", "4"=>"val4"}
@page.save
```

Comment: Should I add `, Hash` so it becomes `serialize :hash, Hash`? If not why is this option available if it saves as a hash anyway?

Comment: tried `serialize :hash` but get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method ;serialize' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: You should add serialize to the model, not the migration.

Comment: Yes, as Dharam mentions, the `serialize :hash` line of code should be added to your Page model.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :json datatype, available in latest postgres 9.3 version onwards, it would be easy to save hash.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `serialize :hash` to the model and then use it while save into the database.